# is it possible to sync an SKSpriteNode with a Video like you can with CALayers?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, calayer, skspritenode

I would like to synchronize the movement of an `SKSpriteNode` with a video. So as the video seeks forward, seeks backward or just plays the `SKSpriteNode` moves accordingly.
I know this can be done easily enough with `CALayers`, but can it be done with `SKSpriteNode`(s) in place of `CALayers`?

```
// 1) Create a sync layer
AVPlayerItem * item = player.currentItem;
AVSynchronizedLayer* syncLayer = [AVSynchronizedLayer synchronizedLayerWithPlayerItem:item];
syncLayer.frame = CGRectMake(10, 220, 300, 10);
syncLayer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor];
[self.view.layer addSublayer:syncLayer];

// 2) Create a sublayer for the synclayer
CALayer *sublayer = [CALayer layer];
sublayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 50); //our black box
sublayer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
[syncLayer addSublayer:sublayer];

// 3) animate the layer!
CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
anim.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(924, 300)];
anim.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(100, 300)];
anim.removedOnCompletion = NO;
anim.beginTime = AVCoreAnimationBeginTimeAtZero;  
anim.duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(item.asset.duration);

NSLog(@"%f",anim.duration);

[sublayer addAnimation:anim forKey:nil];
```

Comment: Yes. I have tried. And I have failed, hence the reason I have asked (those who have far more experience than I) for a little help.

Comment: well then post that code and explain what's happening

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Even I am looking for something like this.